# Change calculation total of a mat-paginator

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, mat-pagination

I have a mat-table where some of rows cant count on total numbers of rows on mat-paginator.
I need that mat paginator calculate total of pages ignoring that rows.
How I can do that?

[table with ignored rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFwpp.png)